# SpringXD JSON parser to Oracle DB

Tags: json, spring, oracle, spring-xd

I am trying to use SpringXD to stream some JSON metrics data to a Oracle database.

I am using this example from here: [SpringXD Example](http://glenn-renfro-dev.blogspot.com/2013/09/adding-new-modules-to-spring-xd-part-1.html)

Http call being made: [EarthquakeJsonExample](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojson/all/hour)

My shell cmd.

```
 stream create earthData --definition "trigger|usgs| jdbc --columns='mag,place,time,updated,tz,url,felt,cdi,mni,alert,tsunami,status,sig,net,code,ids,souces,types,nst,dmin,rms,gap,magnitude_type' --driverClassName=driver --username=username --password --url=url --tableName=Test_Table" --deploy
```

I would like to capture just the properties portion of this JSON response into the given table columns. I got it to the point where it doesn't give me a error on the hashing but instead just deposits a bunch of nulls into the column.

I think my problem is the parsing of the JSON itself. Since really the properties is in the Features array. Can SpringXD distinguish this for me out of the box or will I need to write a custom processor?

Here is a look at what the database looks like after a successful cmd.

[image: What Is put into my database]

Any advice? Im new to parsing JSON in this fashion and im not really sure how to find more documentation or examples with SpringXD itself.

Here is reference to the documentation: [SpringXD Doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transformer in the JDBC sink expects a simple document that can converted to a map of keys/values. You would need to add a transformer upstream, perhaps in your `usgs` processor or even a separate processor. You could use a `#jsonPath` expression to extract the properties key and make it the payload.